# Unity Netcode - Client "Sometimes" spawns bullets at world center instead of fire point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I'm trying to make a 3d shooter game using Unity Netcode for Gameobjects.
On host, everything working fine but on clients bullet prefabs spawning at wrong location.
[image: Here is the GIF]

I tried following tutorials and reading docs but none of them helped. I copied codes from my old perfectly working projects with older netcode versions but exact code didnt properly work in my current project. My current code for spawning bullets is

```
[ServerRpc]
void ShootServerRpc()
{
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoints[0].position, firePoints[0].rotation);
    bullet.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().SpawnWithOwnership(OwnerClientId);
    ShootClientRpc(bullet.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().NetworkObjectId);
}
[ClientRpc]
void ShootClientRpc(ulong _id)
{
    NetworkObject netObj = NetworkManager.Singleton.SpawnManager.SpawnedObjects[_id];
    netObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(netObj.transform.forward * bulletSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

I also tried passing position and rotation parameter instead of using firePoints but that didn't change anything.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: whats more noticable is the host shows it moving..

Comment: Players can move but thats not the point?

Comment: my point is the client doent look to be moving but the host says it is.. it might therefor have conflicting locations and spawn the bullet from where the host says it is, not where it says it is

Comment: I see but wouldnt using parameters instead of firepoints would solve the issue if that was the case? Did I not get it correctly?

Comment: Where is the code for `OldShootClientRpc`?  Which is the one being used, and which is causing the problem?

Comment: Sorry thanks for pointing out I forgot to rename it. You can see it as ShootClientRpc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one week of searching, asking and changing code I finally solved the bug with switching from `2022.3.3f1` to `2021.3.16f1`. Without changing anything else the bug is solved. I believe something was wrong with new versions of the unity.